# javascript not effecting html when I type

Tags: javascript, html

Recently when coding Javascript isn't effecting the HTML unless the entire code is copied and pasted. I have added a photo of notepad++, the simple code on the right is copied and works fine, the one on the right was typed out by me with minor changes to text. any help is appreciated. image:[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ9Nw.png)

Comment: `getElimentById` is not a valid method.

Comment: You spelled element with an "i" instead of an "e".

Comment: [Please add the code to the question instead of adding it as an image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

`getElimentById` should be `getElementById`

Comment: No you're not. Everyone makes mistakes!